# Password incorrect and Internet Recovery Mode -3001f Error

Tags: macos, imac, password, error, internet-recovery

Have an iMac here roughly 2 years old and within the last week the admin account password has stopped working. It is the correct password, used on all of our devices and only IT staff use it. The password has not been changed. (our users use network accounts which have also stopped logging in, however that seems to be a network related issue as other computers are also experiencing this).

I have since attempted to enter internet recovery mode to either a) reset the admin password, or b) reinstall OS X (I believe it is running Yosemite). Both of these I have seen as options to get around the faulty password check.

However, upon booting into recovery mode, I am presented with an exclamation mark over a world icon and the following: apple/support -3001f.

I cannot find a description of this error anywhere. A few for -1006f or -1007f but absolutely zilch for -3001f.

What options to regain control of this Mac exist?

Comment: Is it possible a firewall/configuration is blocking access to Apple servers? This was noted in: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139782/119461

Comment: Actually, I have been wondering that myself - we have had issues with our internet security management blocking the App Store and other Apple servers so this could definitely be affecting connection.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!

Managed to boot into single user mode and edit the password through the command line (both brilliant and a terrifying security issue).

Comment: Very difficult to know without more information. Corruption can occur in any number of ways, ranging from disk problems, to hackers (probably not), or perhaps even a rare bug that you just discovered. If this happens again, I'd worry, but otherwise this may be a one-time event. You may want to run a repair on your disk just to verify that this wasn't caused by filesystem corruption, which doesn't get better with age.

Comment: Funny - not so funny - thing here: we had the exact same problem with another computer which has not been used for a while (simply there to operate a 3D printer). All of our macs are made from the same base image so I am really hoping that the corruption does not stem from there. Might mean potentially building the image from the ground up again :/

Thanks for the input!

Comment: You could try running a disk verify on the image then. I'm assuming the image is read-only. There are ways corruption can work its way into even read-only images, so it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely check this out - don't want a domino effect happening